# Passing a Array of strings to function to read from stdin

Tags: arrays, c, function, arguments

This code is getting into my nervs!

I have a function called by main, which should read from input to an array (ArrayStr) of [5] [20] (five words of 20 chars max each).

But it crashes on gets or scanf or fgets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int MAX_CHARS_STRING = 20;
const int MAX_STRINGS = 5;

int ReadStrings (char **ArrayStr) {
    int string_pos = 0;

    while (string_pos < MAX_STRINGS) {
        gets(ArrayStr[string_pos]);
        string_pos++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int err = 0;
    char ArrayStrings[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_CHARS_STRING];
    err = ReadStrings (ArrayStrings);
    err = WriteStrings (ArrayStrings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well almost everything is wrong on this question, starting from your example not being complete - where is `WriteStrings`, what `scanf`, what `fgets`? Did you get any warnings from the compiler (you should have); these warnings are your error, and should be included into the question; `gets` does not exist in C any more because it is impossible to use securely; you cannot fit a string of 20 characters in an array of 20 characters (you need 21) and most importantly a pointer to pointer is not the same thing as an array of arrays.

Comment: Your posted code does not compile. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
const size_t MAX_CHARS_STRING = 20;
const size_t MAX_STRINGS = 5;

//or better
//#define MAX_CHARS_STRING 20
//#define MAX_STRINGS 5

int WriteStrings (size_t rows, size_t cols, char (*ArrayStr)[cols]) {
    size_t string_pos = 0;

    while (string_pos < rows) {
        printf("String No %zu: `%s`\n", string_pos, ArrayStr[string_pos]);
        string_pos++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int ReadStrings (size_t rows, size_t cols, char (*ArrayStr)[cols]) {
    size_t string_pos = 0;

    while (string_pos < rows) {
        if(!fgets(ArrayStr[string_pos], cols, stdin)) return 0;
        string_pos++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int err = 0;
    char ArrayStrings[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_CHARS_STRING];
    err = ReadStrings (MAX_STRINGS, MAX_CHARS_STRING, ArrayStrings);
    err = WriteStrings (ArrayStrings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. '0___________'. I was getting trouble how to pass the array argument to the function and right using inside it. It was getting my nervs out. I was trying to declare the argument as "char *ArrayStr[]", "char **ArrayStr" and also "(char *ArrayStr)[]" without success and also getting crashes probably by the use of gets and not fgets. Thank you for your patience.